# Not able to see Parallel Tasks window in Visual studio 2010 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, task-parallel-library

The parallel task window should be under Debug > Windows in Visual Studio. However, I see only "Breakpoints" there. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The menu item for the window is only available when you're debugging.  Are you debugging when you do this?

Comment: +1 @Chris. I was not debugging when I tried it. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+D,K</kbd> as shown [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Parallel-Tasks-New-Visual-Studio-2010-Debugger-Window.aspx) whenever the execution of your program hits a breakpoint in Debug mode.